# Difference of two columns if condition is met

Tags: pandas, dataframe

To get the difference between two columns of a pandas dataframe when specifying a condition I'm currently using the following code. For example, to get difference between column `A` and `B` for the rows where `A > B`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [4,5,6,7], 'B' : [1,2,10,11]}); df
   A   B
0  4   1
1  5   2
2  6  10
3  7  11

df2 = df.loc[df.A > df.B]
df2.A - df2.B
0    3
1    3
```

Is there a way to "pipe" this instead of creating the temporary dataframe `df2` above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method using [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.eval.html) and has [`high performance`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/enhancingperf.html#pandas-eval-performance) while working with huge data:

```
df.loc[df.A > df.B].eval('A - B')

0    3
1    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply join the two commands and select the columns you want to subtract:

```
In [2337]: df.loc[df.A > df.B]['A'] - df.loc[df.A > df.B]['B']
Out[2337]: 
0    3
1    3
dtype: int64
```